# Как правильно перевести float в int

Tags: php

Пишу такой код:

```
$sum = 161.98;
$sum = $sum * 100;

var_dump($sum);         // float(16198)
var_dump((int)$sum);    // int(16197)
```

Почему при переводе в int теряется единица

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать округление в большую сторону

```
var_dump((int)ceil($sum));
```

Answer (score 3):

> Почему при переводе в int теряется единица

Потому, что из-за особенностей арифметики с плавающей точкой 161.98*100 может быть равно 16197.9999999.

При выводе float это учитывается, а при преобразовании в int дробная часть просто отбрасывается.

Что с этим делать - округлять перед преобразованием. Только не так, как советует IvanTokar, а до ближайшего целого, через `round`

Comment: А 16198.000000001 не может получится ? т.е. только в меньшую сторону может выйти ?

Comment: Может быть в обе стороны. Но если погрешность в бОльшую, то отбрасывание дробной части даст именно тот результат, что вам и нужен.